# How to "Legitimize" a PHP Helper Application that essentially uses CSRF for Authentication?

Tags: java, php, single-sign-on, csrf, saml

In a nutshell, I wrote a PHP application that uses CSRF to piggyback off of one of our other applications, which is not written in PHP (liferay). This helper application (various utility forms for faculty) is designed to have its endpoints placed in iframes.

Well, we're moving from an internally hosted Wso2 instance to Azure, and the iframes are blocked from loading microsoftonline.com. If you manually navigate to the helper application, the rest of the requests from the iframes work fine.

For lack of a better question, how do I replace the CSRF-reliant authentication with something more legitimate? I don't think we're going to be able to make the current scheme we have work, but I don't know where to start either.

### Edit

Azure won't allow the iframe to open a session because the iframe isn't allowed to embed the page.

[image: iframe can't open microsoftonline.com]

Comment: Huh? CSRF isn't "authentication". Please explain in more detail.

Comment: It relies on the parent application being logged in to initialize a session in the nested application. There are iframes in the parent application that load the helper, but on the first request, the helper needs to hit the identity server.

Comment: I don't know if "CSRF" is the perfectly correct term, but it seemed like the best fit because the two applications have different subdomains, but the one relies on the other being logged in to function.